# Create protobuf with json values

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

is it possible to merge or set protobuf message values with matching json values???

example json:

```json
{id: 1, channel: 2, userIsLogged:true}
```

and a proto definition:

```proto
message ServerResponse {
    int32 id = 1
    Result result = 2
    int32 channel = 3
    bool userExists = 4
    bool userIsLogged =5
}
```

Is there a tool or proto utility to create the proto message without setting the properties individually?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which language you are using with Protobuf message. `Protobuf` has provides some toolkits to parse Proto3 message from Json.

If you are using `Java`, you could use [`JsonFormat`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java#L469) to parse Json into Protobuf message:

```java
JsonFormat.parser().merge(json_string, builder);
```

If you are using `C++`, you could use [`json_util`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.json_util) to parse Json:

```cpp
#include <google/protobuf/util/json_util.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ServerResponse sr
  // Parse the json_string into sr.
  google::protobuf::util::JsonParseOptions options;
  JsonStringToMessage(json_string, &sr, options);
}
```

For other languages, you could check [Protobuf reference](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/overview) to find a related toolkit.